# SqlAlchemy SQL Server Ambiguous Column Name Error

Tags: python, sql-server, ubuntu, sqlalchemy

I have an issue that I could not manage. I am developing an FastApi SqlAlchemy App connected to SQL Server. I have created my models and views on locally. But when I deployed an server The following error occurred. I have tried Ubuntu, Linux, Windows VMs but the situation is same.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, Text, Column, DATE
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import select, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, Query
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey 
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql import pymssql
import urllib
import datetime

from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import Date

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
                             "SERVER=MYSERVER"
                             "UID=MYUSERNAME"
                             "PWD=MYPASSWD"
                             "DATABASE=MYDB"
                             "Trusted_Connection=no;"
                             "Integrated Security=false;")

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))

engine.connect()

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata

session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

class Users(Base):
__table__ = Table('astencube_users', Base.metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

print(session.query(*Users.__table__.columns).all())
```

This is a part of my app I am trying to print a table but when I try to make any query I got error below. On my local machine there is no error when I deploy any machine it appears. Also the error gives me a parameter which represents my table but when I check the other tables still problem occurs. On my local machine there is no problem. Why is it happening?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1799, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 717, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Ambiguous column name 'constraint_schema'. (209) (SQLExecDirectW)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 35, in <module>
    class Users(Base):
  File "file.py", line 36, in Users
    __table__ = Table('astencube_users', Base.metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
  File "<string>", line 2, in __new__
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 298, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 607, in __new__
    metadata._remove_table(name, schema)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 602, in __new__
    table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 677, in _init
    self._autoload(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 712, in _autoload
    conn_insp.reflect_table(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 795, in reflect_table
    self._reflect_fk(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 948, in _reflect_fk
    fkeys = self.get_foreign_keys(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 564, in get_foreign_keys
    return self.dialect.get_foreign_keys(
  File "<string>", line 2, in get_foreign_keys
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 55, in cache
    ret = fn(self, con, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/base.py", line 2498, in wrap
    return _switch_db(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/base.py", line 2522, in _switch_db
    return fn(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/base.py", line 3400, in get_foreign_keys
    for r in connection.execute(s).fetchall():
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1286, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params, _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 325, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1478, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1842, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2023, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1799, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 717, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Ambiguous column name 'constraint_schema'. (209) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: WITH fk_info AS (
    SELECT
        ischema_ref_con.constraint_schema,
        ischema_ref_con.constraint_name,
        ischema_key_col.ordinal_position,
        ischema_key_col.table_schema,
        ischema_key_col.table_name,
        ischema_ref_con.unique_constraint_schema,
        ischema_ref_con.unique_constraint_name,
        ischema_ref_con.match_option,
        ischema_ref_con.update_rule,
        ischema_ref_con.delete_rule,
        ischema_key_col.column_name AS constrained_column
    FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS ischema_ref_con
        INNER JOIN
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ischema_key_col ON
            ischema_key_col.table_schema = ischema_ref_con.constraint_schema
            AND ischema_key_col.constraint_name =
            ischema_ref_con.constraint_name
    WHERE ischema_key_col.table_name = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))
        AND ischema_key_col.table_schema = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))
),
constraint_info AS (
    SELECT
        ischema_key_col.constraint_schema,
        ischema_key_col.constraint_name,
        ischema_key_col.ordinal_position,
        ischema_key_col.table_schema,
        ischema_key_col.table_name,
        ischema_key_col.column_name
    FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ischema_key_col
),
index_info AS (
    SELECT
        sys.schemas.name AS index_schema,
        sys.indexes.name AS index_name,
        sys.index_columns.key_ordinal AS ordinal_position,
        sys.schemas.name AS table_schema,
        sys.objects.name AS table_name,
        sys.columns.name AS column_name
    FROM
        sys.indexes
        INNER JOIN
        sys.objects ON
            sys.objects.object_id = sys.indexes.object_id
        INNER JOIN
        sys.schemas ON
            sys.schemas.schema_id = sys.objects.schema_id
        INNER JOIN
        sys.index_columns ON
            sys.index_columns.object_id = sys.objects.object_id
            AND sys.index_columns.index_id = sys.indexes.index_id
        INNER JOIN
        sys.columns ON
            sys.columns.object_id = sys.indexes.object_id
            AND sys.columns.column_id = sys.index_columns.column_id
)
    SELECT
        fk_info.constraint_schema,
        fk_info.constraint_name,
        fk_info.ordinal_position,
        fk_info.constrained_column,
        constraint_info.table_schema AS referred_table_schema,
        constraint_info.table_name AS referred_table_name,
        constraint_info.column_name AS referred_column,
        fk_info.match_option,
        fk_info.update_rule,
        fk_info.delete_rule
    FROM
        fk_info INNER JOIN constraint_info ON
            constraint_info.constraint_schema =
                fk_info.unique_constraint_schema
            AND constraint_info.constraint_name =
                fk_info.unique_constraint_name
            AND constraint_info.ordinal_position = fk_info.ordinal_position
    UNION
    SELECT
        fk_info.constraint_schema,
        fk_info.constraint_name,
        fk_info.ordinal_position,
        fk_info.constrained_column,
        index_info.table_schema AS referred_table_schema,
        index_info.table_name AS referred_table_name,
        index_info.column_name AS referred_column,
        fk_info.match_option,
        fk_info.update_rule,
        fk_info.delete_rule
    FROM
        fk_info INNER JOIN index_info ON
            index_info.index_schema = fk_info.unique_constraint_schema
            AND index_info.index_name = fk_info.unique_constraint_name
            AND index_info.ordinal_position = fk_info.ordinal_position

    ORDER BY constraint_schema, constraint_name, ordinal_position
]
[parameters: ('astencube_users', 'dbo')]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

Comment: I suggest you use the SQL Server Profiler to see what the SQL being sent it... clearly there is an error with it.

Comment: @Dale K when I trace it I got same error messages. [Photo1](https://i.imgur.com/2oAQpyi.png) [Photo2](https://i.imgur.com/jTV6zGM.png)
In photo1 there is a error and it stops exec sp_unprepare 2 step but the successful one the all steps completed.

Comment: I can't see an error message in the trace, but anyway you need to work out which line the error is occurring on and then extract the exact SQL from it, then you will see the ambiguous column name.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was because of the SqlAlchemy version.The version in my local machine was 1.4.25 when I install newest version to any where I got the sql error shown above.So this problem was happened because of the version.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wading through your code above we find this exact error message:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Ambiguous column name 'constraint_schema'. (209) (SQLExecDirectW)")

So when we look to see where you've referenced `constraint_schema` in your code, there are a few places.

For most of them you have correctly used 2-part naming to avoid any ambiguity.

However your final order by clause does not:

```sql
ORDER BY constraint_schema, constraint_name, ordinal_position
```

P.S. the best way to debug this stuff yourself in the future is to take the SQL code and run it directly against the SQL Server i.e. eliminate Python from the equation as it just muddies the waters.